Even if text issue prefixes is mentioned in cypress.config.js, Qytera-Gmbh/cypress-xray-plugin failed to upload result to xray
I have JIRA and xray integrated into my project. The project key is "ABC". prefixes for XRAY is "TEST_". I have integrated https://qytera-gmbh.github.io/projects/cypress-xray-plugin plugin to upload the test execution results to JIRA-Xray.
but results are not being uploaded. I am getting error: "No test issue keys found in tags:"
versions:
"cypress": "^13.16.1",
"cypress-xray-plugin": "^7.4.2",
Feature File:
Feature: Verify Admin can access and control <>
@TEST_XR-6033 @TESTSET_XR-6035
Scenario: xr-3550-Admin-Validate..
    Given user is logged..
    When ...
    Then ...
    (can't put all gherkin due to project restriction)

Cypress.config.js has the config set as below:
e2e: {
experimentalOriginDependencies: true,
experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
   const fixedOn = fix(on);
    await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(fixedOn, config);
    await configureXrayPlugin(fixedOn,config,{
            jira: {
              projectKey: "ABC",       
              url: "..", 
              attachVideos: true,
              createTestExecutionIssues: true,
              testExecutionIssueSummary: "Test Execution - Regression Cycle",
              testExecutionIssueDescription: "Test Execution - Regression Cycle", 
            },
            xray: {
              uploadResults: true,
              uploadScreenshots: true
            },
            cucumber: {
                featureFileExtension: ".feature",
                prefixes: {
                  test: "TEST_"
              }
            },
            plugin: {
              logDirectory: "cypress/logs",
              debug: true
            }
        });
    fixedOn("file:preprocessor", async (file) => {
        await syncFeatureFile(file);
        const cucumberPlugin = createBundler({
            plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        });
        return cucumberPlugin(file);
    });
    return config;
},

in my project JIRA & XRAY are integrated but they are separate projects on the cloud instace. Hence, project key is "ABC" and test cases/executions I create starts with "XR-xx"
Need assistance here on what's going wrong or any additional set up needed so that plugin identify key and upload result to Xray?

As of version 7.4.2, the plugin can only detect Cucumber scenario tags that contain the project key (see source code). So unfortunately, you cannot define project key ABC and use tags containing project XR. You will need to choose one or the other. Either define projectKey: "XR", or annote your scenarios with issue keys such as @TEST_ABC-123.
